# Unable to clear text in popup when it is closed by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a popup menu and there is an iframe code as a text in the popup. I have a button to enable the iframe code text. And then I need to disable or display:none the iframe text when the popup is closed. So the next time I open the popup, again I have to click on the button to enable the text. I made display:none the iframe text with the popup close button, but I'm unable to do it with click out of the popup modal. When I apply the Display:none to the modal class or fade class, I can't even enable the text. How I disable the text when the popup closed?

Here is the code:

```js
 $(".embed-btn").on("click", function() {
  $(".embed-iframe").css("display", "block");
 });

 $(".close").on("click", function() {
  $(".embed-iframe").css("display", "none");
 });
```

```css
.embed-iframe{
 display: none;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 border: 1px solid #ececec;
 background-color: #fafafa;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<button class="btn open" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">OPEN</button>

<div class="modal fade main-div-1" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-div" role="document">
  <div class="col-md-3 img-div">
   <img src="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9 modal-content content-div">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
        <button class="btn embed-btn">Enable Code</button>
    <div class="embed-iframe">
     <span class="embed-iframe-text">
      &lt;iframe width="" height="" src="" frameborder="" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
     </span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use modal box built in functions
open() & close() in place of hide and show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I disable the text when the popup closed?

You can use Bootstrap's built-in modal events to handle this scenario.

```js
$('#modal1').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $(".embed-iframe").css("display", "none");
})
```

With this, you can remove the lines of code below as well since the `.close` button will trigger the `hide.bs.modal` event as well.

```js
$(".close").on("click", function() {
  $(".embed-iframe").css("display", "none");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add on modal close event listener and you are good to go.

Check out [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#events)

Like this

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
 $(".embed-iframe").css("display", "none");
})
```

```js
$(".embed-btn").on("click", function() {
  $(".embed-iframe").css("display", "block");
});

$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
 $(".embed-iframe").css("display", "none");
})
```

```css
.embed-iframe {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<button class="btn open" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">OPEN</button>

<div class="modal fade main-div-1" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-div" role="document">
    <div class="col-md-3 img-div">
      <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 modal-content content-div">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button class="btn embed-btn">Enable Code</button>
        <div class="embed-iframe">
          <span class="embed-iframe-text">
      &lt;iframe width="" height="" src="" frameborder="" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
     </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check below working link,
http://jsfiddle.net/brahmpragya/mwcsbyv3/12/

In this I solved the issue. Just small issue that on modal close hide the iframe code.

Here is the code:

```js
 $(".embed-btn").on("click", function() {
  $(".embed-iframe").css("display", "block");
 });

 $(".close").on("click", function() {
  $(".embed-iframe").css("display", "none");
 });
```

```css
.embed-iframe{
 display: none;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 border: 1px solid #ececec;
 background-color: #fafafa;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<button class="btn open" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">OPEN</button>

<div class="modal fade main-div-1" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-div" role="document">
  <div class="col-md-3 img-div">
   <img src="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9 modal-content content-div">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
        <button class="btn embed-btn">Enable Code</button>
    <div class="embed-iframe">
     <span class="embed-iframe-text">
      &lt;iframe width="" height="" src="" frameborder="" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
     </span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```